# Почему к одним и тем же командам существует по несколько мануалов?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Например: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=ls&op=&cx=003883529982892832976%3A5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com%2F&ref=&ss=2351j954255j9

Причём все действующие насколько я понимаю.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как написано на самих страницах, эти программы различаются. Например, в случае с `ls`, одна страница для стандартного `ls`, другая - для `ls`, удовлетворяющего стандарту POSIX (может понадобиться, например, для тестирования скриптов, которые должны быть переносимы), третья - из пакета, обеспечивающего совместимость с ОС Plan 9 From Bell Labs.

Comment: А как отличить стандартный `ls`?

Comment: @Hipster "Стандартный" - это тот, где написано `Provided by: coreutils_8.25-2ubuntu2_i386`. `coreutils` - пакет со всеми основными утилитами.

Comment: @Hipster   Вы учитывали BSD, Solaris, AIX, HP-UX, Darvin, MINIX, UNIX V5    у всех различная реализация "стандартных" програм. веду исследование и анализ https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/spices/cix-unix-land.org